# Delete numerous NoData rasters from database

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, nodata

I've got >1000 rasters in a folder with about 10% containing no data. I'm looking for a method, preferably through ArcGIS (also open to QGIS, GDAL, etc.), to run through the folder and delete all of the no data rasters. Is there a script to take care of this? Logically, I could just delete all of the files under a certain size, but logic doesn't always apply to ArcGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a model builder approach in ArcGIS which will delete all rasters where all cells are nodata.

[image: Model for deleting rasters that are all nodata]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with open source tools via **gdal_translate**:

```
for %i in (*.tif) do gdal_translate -a_nodata 0 %i %~ni_NODATA.tif
```

The OSGeo4W Shell command  is very simple and will create new raster data without NoData around images.

[gdal_translate: hide nodata - video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/149563251/2014_pd/GDAL_RemoveNoDATA.mp4)